# Any tools for relationship between XML files

Tags: xml, relationship

I have a set of XML configuration files, which are long and complex. The structure is that some attributes are defined in a parent xml and are imported and overridden by the children xml.

Because of 20 odd such files, it becomes confusing to understand which properties are imported and whats the relationship between the files.

Are there any tools to visually represent the relationship between xml (like class diagrams in java)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try [Altova XML Editor](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/)... 
I'm not 100% sure if it does that, but is a great tool for working with XML.